The bot doesn't play music (discord.py)
The code works fine, but when using the command in guild the bot enters the voice channel but doesn't play music, immediately console gives: ffmpeg process 56560 successfully terminated with return code of 3199971767.
import discord
import youtube_dl
import ffmpeg
import requests
from discord.ext import commands

class music(commands.Cog, name = 'music'):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False


        self.music_queue = []
        self.YTDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'True'}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn -filter "volume=0.25"'}

        self.voice_client = None
        
    @commands.command(name="play")
    async def play(self, ctx, url):
        if not ctx.message.author.voice:
            await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel.")
            return

        self.voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        if self.voice_client and self.voice_client.is_connected():
            await self.voice_client.move_to(self.voice_channel)
        else:
            self.voice_client = await self.voice_channel.connect()

        api_key = "my_key"
        video_id = url.split("v=")[1]
        api_url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={video_id}&key={api_key}"

        response = requests.get(api_url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            title = data["items"][0]["snippet"]["title"]
            audio_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}"
            self.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegOpusAudio(audio_url))
            await ctx.send("Now playing: " + title)
        else:
            await ctx.send("Unable to fetch video information.")

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(music(bot))

I tried to rewrite some YTDL and FFMPEG options
(tried to replace "noplaylist" option on "False" and terminal sent:
"discord.player: ffmpeg process 51124 successfully terminated with return code of 4294967295").
Also i checked the updates of modules.
